# Função que transforme a data em formato brasileiro e americano?

Tags: php, data

Como seria uma função que ao ser chamada, transforme qualquer data (válida) para o contrário?

Por exemplo, digitei:

`21/04/2017` vai retornar como `2017/04/21`;

Se eu digitar:

`2017/12/31` vai transformar em `31/12/2017`;

Comment: Eu havia escrito errado :(

Answer (score 0):

Esta função faz a conversão usando `strtotime()`:

```
<?php
function convData($i){
   $i = str_replace('/','-',$i);
   return str_replace('-','/',strlen(end(explode('-',$i))) == 4 ?
   date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i)) : date("d-m-Y", strtotime($i)));
}


echo convData('21/04/2017');
echo '-----';
echo convData('2017/04/21');
?>
```

**[Teste no Ideone](https://ideone.com/1ijUcg)**.

**Obs.:** `strtotime()` não trabalha corretamente com `/`, por isso é preciso fazer um `replace` de `/` para `-` na função.